# how to run a java tool without running java in task manager

Tags: java, windows, exe, launch4j

I developed a tool using java, I have a created an APP.exe using Launch4j and when I execute the APP.exe, Java runs along with the Tool. I can see it in Task Manager. How to run the tool alone without running java? or all tool developed in java needs java to run along with the tool?                       I need like: when i execute APP.exe  and if i see the task Manager only App.exe should be displayed in Task Manager and Java should not run (like standalone tool, eg: netbeans).

Answer (score 0):

Java will always run. Either like a separeted process or within the .exe app by been loaded via the java.dll.

You can choosse this on Launch4j.

Comment: How to run java within the application (i.e) when I open the task manager the application only should visible not java.